# what is '.js' doing at the beginning of a style in a stylesheet

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having to edit somebody else's code and they seem to have used a whole load of jQuery for something that would otherwise seem quite simple to me - an html form.

When I switch off some of the jQuery I lose a load of styles and it seems that is because all the styles are pre-fixed with `.js` eg:

```
.js .classname{width:50px}
```

When I take out the `.js` bit it works, but am I missing something? What is the point in this (seemingly) over-complicated methodology?

Taking out the jquery doesn't change the markup
`<div class='classname'>`. Sorry for lack of code, its somebody elses. I don't know jquery and would rather not use it.

Comment: They might be classes that were added with js -- maybe a style a previous programmer used? Hard to tell without seeing more code.

Comment: Without seeing the rest of the code, my guess would be that the `js` class is applied to a root element in case JavaScript is supported and active in the user's browser. Otherwise, the un-prefixed classes would kick in.

Comment: I know I've not been too generous with my example, because I'm looking at a mess made by someone else I'm afraid. But taking out the jquery doesn't change the markup <div class='classname'>. Is '.js' a kind of pseudo class? of is it something that this person has named themselves? Ta

Comment: It's just a plain selector `.js` is a class that is most likely added to the body/html element. By removing `.js` from the selector, you are not actually changing the target of the selector (the target is still `.classname`), just making it a little less specific, which is why it `still works`.

Comment: @Boaz, ah so its designed to work only if javascript is working...! that would be it. Nothing to do with the jquery?

Comment: @gavin Hard to be absolutely certain, but it's a good bet. See GolezTrol's answer as well.

Comment: @gavin - I'd bet (but I can't be certain without seeing it) that it comes from a Modernizr script

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a common trick. The `js` class is added to a main element (usually HTML or sometimes BODY) using Javascript. This allows you to easily make adjustments in CSS that apply when Javascript is active/supported or not. For instance, you can show a 'refresh' button by default and hide it as soon as auto-refresh javascript events are activated.

So there's nothing special about it. Just something your predecessor has added himself/herself.

Comment: Ah, thanks. One question I suppose - is this 'js' class added dynamically with javascript? (I can't see it in the markup), or by jquery in my case probably..?

Comment: @gavin - it's commonly found in a Modernizr script, so I'd guess that's where it's coming from.

Comment: Yes. jQuery is also Javascript. ;) Someone might have written a simple script like `$('html').addClass('js')`, but as Adam suggests, it might be done by a library like Modernizr as well (which is basically still Javascript). I haven't used Modernizr myself, but I *have* added the `js` class to the HTML of a website to apply this trick. :)

Comment: Great, thanks. I suppose taking it out of the code in my case wouldn't be all that bad as the styles I wish to apply don't depend on having js or not?

Comment: If you want to apply styling regardless of having javascript (or the `js` class) or not, you can just exclude it from your CSS selectors. Use `.classname{width:50px}` instead of `.js .classname{width:50px}`. Leave the code that adds the class. It might be used by existing functionality on the page.